# swift 4 To the variable assignment

Tags: ios, swift

I use swift 4 `setValuesForKeys()` assignment，it will not work，The “content” of this variable，But it will enter

```
override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forUndefinedKey key: String) {}
```

[image]

I use it on the swift 3.2, it can work，
What reason is this excuse me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an update about `@objc` and `dynamic` in Swift 4, if you want to use KVC, add keyword mark it as an OBJC property:

```
@objc var content = ""
```

Comment: Thank you so much . You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this

```
override func setValuesForKeys(_ keyedValues: [String : Any]) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want